# Как адаптировать слайдер swiper?

Tags: веб-программирование, swiper

Хочу чтобы если экран больше 750 то было 2 слайда, если меньше, то 1. Что не так?

```
slidesPerView:2, 
    spaceBetween:30, 
    loop:!0, 
    breakpoints:{ 
        750 : { 
            slidesPerView: 1 
        }, 
        991: { 
            slidesPerView: 2 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Сперва задается общий параметр, который будет всегда использоваться, а затем он переопределяется для конкретных разрешений:

```
slidesPerView: 1, // по-умолчанию для всех случаев
spaceBetween: 30,
loop:!0, 
breakpoints:{ 
// для window width >= 750
  750 : {
    slidesPerView: 2 
  },  
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]